Master database backup sufficient for TDE enabled feature in sql server
I have master database backup, is it enough for tde enabled instance or do I need to take care of master key backup as well.

What is your end goal?

For rebuilding VM from scratch. At the time restoration of master database on new server.

Does this answer your question? Can I recover a TDE certificate by restoring the MASTER database?

Charlie's linked post is an answer assuming you're keeping the server certificate in master and not somewhere else.
